# Nested List, Multiple Layouts

Tags: sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

In Sencha Touch 2.1, I have the following nested list defined:

```
xtype: 'NestedList',
docked: 'top',
ui: 'light',
store: treeStore,
detailCard: true,
detailContainer: // Reference to a Another Panel
```

I can get the Nested List to appear, but adding items via JSON is proving problematic. Here's a sample of my JSON:

```
[
    {
       "BranchID" : 4,
       "BranchName" : "Branch Name",
       "Jobs" : [
          {
             "JobOrderID" : 75,
             "JobTitle" : "Job Title",
             "leaf" : true
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

And here is my Tree Store and List Item:

```
// Define a List Item:
Ext.define('Branch', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'BranchID',
            'BranchName'
        ]
    }
});

var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Branch',
    defaultRootProperty: 'items',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/region.php'
    }
});
```

I can see that data/region.php is being called, and it's correctly returning JSON - but the list items do not show up. How do I get the list items to show up?

Additionally, I'd like to use a different layout for the leaf nodes - and to have those leaf nodes pull up a request in a separate panel. How do I identify the panel, so I can reference it in the DetailContainer section of my NestedList?

What I'm looking for:

1. List of Branches
2. Tap on a Branch, list all jobs
3. Tap a job, details show in other panel.

I've read the documentation, but it seems a little sparse on more complex implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my Sencha Experience, my advice would be never to use `Ext.NestedList`. Of course they are quite handy when your model is very simple but hard to customize when you model contains associations for instance.

So what I would do (and did) is to use an `Ext.navigation.View` and push new lists as you tap on items of previous lists. This is the exact same concept as a `Ext.NestedList` so it won't overload your application.

[Here is an example based on your data](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#vsY1o)

If you have any question feel free to ask

Hope this helped

Comment: Champion effort! That will do just nicely - thank you so very much for your timely answer!

Comment: I'm new to sencha and this example would be a huge help for me. However, the website you referenced is no longer active. Would you be so kind as to post your example elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think your defaultRootProperty is wrong for the treeStore.

It should be

```
defaultRootProperty: 'Jobs',
```

[API reference](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-defaultRootProperty)

Comment: I gave it a whirl, but it didn't help - the accepted answer provided a working solution given my data - thanks for trying however.